# Is there any way to update Skype preview?

Tags: windows, windows-10, skype

Since the last update of Windows 10, Microsoft added an app for Skype, called Skype Preview.

It's going pretty well, I like the minimalist design, but has some flaws. I can not see the images the people sent to me. I'm trying to upgrade to the latest version, but  i can't find anything. Not even in the store.

Comment: If you have it installed, Your already, running the current version.

Comment: Maybe, there's no beta available?

Comment: Nope; If your running Version 1607 you have the current version of the application

Comment: If you want the preview preview version, install the insider preview builds of Windows 10.  DO NOT do this on a production PC these build expire after a period of time if they are not updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are already using the latest version, so you cannot update it because there is no newer version to update to. In this case it looks like you will need to wait for a new update to arrive first before you can update.